# Postgresql get references from a dictionary

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to build a request to get the data from a table, but some of those columns have foreign keys I would like to replace by the associated keyword in one request.

Basically there's

table A with column 1:PKA-ID and column 2:name.
table B with column 1:PKB-ID, column 2:FKA-ID, column 3:amount.

I want to get all the lines in table B but with all foreign keys replaced by the associated names in table A.

I started building a request with a subrequest + alias to get that, but ofc I have more than one result per subrequest, yet I can't find a way to link that subrequest to the ID of table B [might be exhausted, dumb or both] from the main request. I did something like that:

```
SELECT (SELECT "NAME" FROM A JOIN B ON ID = FKA-ID) AS name, amount FROM TABLEB;
```

it feels so simple of a request yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a join in the subselect.

```
SELECT pkb_id,
  (SELECT name FROM a WHERE a.pka_id = b.fka_id),
  amount
FROM b;
```

(See it live in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e6100/3)).

The subselect query runs for each and every row of its parent select and has the parent row available from the context.

---

You can also use a simple join.

```
SELECT b.pkb_id, a.name, b.amount
FROM b, a
WHERE a.pka_id = b.fka_id;
```

Note that the join version puts less restrictions on the PostgreSQL query optimizer so in some cases the join version might work faster. (For example, in PostgreSQL 9.6 the join might utilize multiple CPU units, cf. [Parallel Query](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Parallel_Query)).

Comment: Thanks, this helps, I'm currently searching myself, but I'll ask in the mean time: there's in fact two referencies to the A table, with two FKA, they could be identical in theory but most of the time they're not, how would it apply?

Comment: Tried something like that but nope: SELECT b."ID", a."fka" as n1, b."VALUE1", a."fka" as n2, b."VALUE2", b."VALUE3", b."VALID" FROM public."BTABLE" as b, public."ATABLE" as a WHERE n1 = a."ID" AND n2 = a."ID"

Comment: well, you helped, I recreated my problem and solved it on SQL fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94ba69/8 , but I don't get how it worked since I never referenced TABLEB in the sub requests, I think that is what got me confused, anyways thanks! [SELECT `PK-ID-B`, (SELECT `NAME` FROM TABLEA WHERE `FKA-ID1` = `PK-ID-A`), `VALUE1`, (SELECT `NAME` FROM TABLEA WHERE `FKA-ID2` = `PK-ID-A`), `VALUE2` FROM TABLEB;]

Comment: - *I never referenced TABLEB in the sub requests* - Yep, the row from the outer query is already in the inner query context. - *there's in fact two referencies to the A table, with two FKA, they could be identical in theory but most of the time they're not, how would it apply?* - How about http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94ba69/16 ?